# netatalk use system users on Debian

Tags: networking, debian, file-sharing

I have Debian 7.3 (wheezy) installed on a VM with Mac OS X host. I didn't install UI like GNOME.

Now I installed netatalk (via apt-get) to use AFP to connect my Mac to the VM. It essentially works but I want netatalk to use the default system users (passwd / shadow files) for authentication. I didn't configure anything except this try in the `/etc/netatalk/afpd.conf`:

```
- -passwdfile=/etc/passwd/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem. I was using the root user, as I didn't want to add new users (it's a local development-test-server which doesn't have to be secure). And the root user is disabled in netatalk.

Now I added another user and it's working fine!